# Identifying vectors with 5 highest and 5 lowest values for a particular row in the df

Tags: r

I have a data frame as shown below:

```
    group     respondent nteachers totalq3 totalq4 totalq5 totalq6 totalq7
1       2            You         2       5       4       4       5       5
2       2  Your Teachers         2      10       8       9      10      10
119  1001 All Principals        NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
120  1002   All Teachers        NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
```

There are additional vectors that go beyond totalq7 (through totalq53) but this snippet of data should suffice.

What I need is some way of identifying vectors totalq3 through totalq53 in descending order of the values for "Your Teachers". Then I flag the 5 vectors with the highest values for "Your Teachers" and output these 5 to xtable. Finally the process has to be repeated to identify the 5 vectors with the smallest values for "Your Teachers".

What is the trick here? Any and all tips would be much appreciated.

Ani

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a dataframe named 'dat', this would be the column names in the order of the second row of 'dat'.

```
names(dat)[-(1:3)][order( dat[2, -(1:3)]) ]
```

So the highest five respondent values would be in:

```
 tail( names(dat)[-(1:3)][order( dat[2, -(1:3)]) ], 5)
```

And the column names with the five lowest values:

```
head( names(dat)[-(1:3)][order( dat[2, -(1:3)]) ], 5)
```

To get the reduced dataset for passage to xtable, just use "heads or tails":

```
 dat[ , head( names(dat)[-(1:3)][order( dat[2, -(1:3)]) ], 5) ]
```

Here is the test set:

```
dat <- read.table(text="    group     respondent nteachers totalq3 totalq4 totalq5 totalq6 totalq7
1       2            'You'         2       5       4       4       5       5
2       2  'Your Teachers'         2      10       8       9      10      10
119  1001 'All Principals'        NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
120  1002   'All Teachers'        NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA", header=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
inc <- order(data[data$respondent == 'Your Teachers',-(1:3)])
dec <- order(data[data$respondent == 'Your Teachers',-(1:3)], decreasing = T)
xtable(data[,3+inc[1:5]])
xtable(data[,3+dec[1:5]])
```

Comment: Thanks Dason and Julius; that helped and I learnt a lot. Much appreciated.